# How to get parameters sent by ExtJs in a Zend controller?

Tags: extjs, get, zend-framework2

I need to access the parameters sent by my ExtJs code in my Zend controller. I tried the following:

1. $this->getRequest()->getContent() - This gets me the closest to my objective, it returns a key value pair of the parameters. But it is a string, so I can't access the keys.
2. Created an instance of the Zend Http Request class and tried `getQuery`, `getParams`, but no luck.

The method is GET, I found it using `getMethod()`.

This is what I get in my Request object.

```
[content:protected] => {"method":"getActivities","params":{"controller":"reader","page":1,"skip":0,"limit":50},"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":4} 
)
```

Is there a way to solve this? I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$content = json_decode($this->getRequest()->getContent()); 
print_r($content);
```

Comment: Read point 2. I have created an instance of the Request class!

Comment: Yes! It is inside my controller.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Each instance of request object creates a new request. The new request won't have any parameters. You need to get the current request using getRequest() method.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Don't create a new instance  of zend http request just use $this->getRequest() in your controller without creating an instance and then calling $intance->getRequest();

Comment: I tried it mate! Used `$this->getRequest()` and `$request->getRequest()` ($request is an instance of the Zend/Http/Request class)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51928/discussion-between-jay-bhatt-and-rutwick-gangurde)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request::getParams()

Comment: [`Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Http.PhpEnvironment.Request.html) - looks like you're using ZF2. You should have mentioned that in the first place. **EDIT:** ok, I see you updated the tag - nvm then :)